# Finding A, B such that A + B = M?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, merge

I have generated two arrays of random integers, `X` and `Y`, both of length `n`, and my goal is to find integer `a` in `X` and integer `b` in `Y` such that `a + b = m`, where `m` is given by the user. This is not a difficult problem to solve, except for my time constraint being O(n*log n) explicitly, that is, not O(n^2) and not O(n).

I realize both merge sort and quick sort (among others) are of this time complexity, but I cannot figure out how to implement them for this specific situation, because there are multiple arrays involved.

Other information that might be helpful: `n` is not to be immense, probably less than 50. The values within the arrays are all randomized from 1 to 100 and are not pre-sorted, though I could sort them if need be.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Honestly no I haven't, because my ideas all involve brute-force checking each number in one array with each number in the other, and as far as I'm informed, that does not follow a O(n*logn) model.

Comment: If the numbers are in the range 1 to 100, you can use a counting-based sort which is `O(n)`, and much easier to program. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). This still makes the overall complexity `O(n log n)` because binary search is `O(log n)`.

Comment: In my limited experience/knowledge of sorting algorithms, I have only ever seen counting sort used to numerically order numbers (smallest to largest). How would I manipulate the counting sort to compare two values against a third one - when both values come from separate arrays?

Comment: @StarCruz First, sort one array. Then iterate the other one, the desired value in the second being the difference between the first one (you're iterating) and the desired number `m`. That is, binary search for `(m - iterator.next())` in the second array.

Comment: First sort array `Y`. Then iterate over `X`. For every value `a` in `X` see if `m - a` is in `Y` using binary search. This has complexity `O(n log n)`. You can do it in `O(n)` time using `HashSet`, but that apparently isn't allowed.

Comment: Wow this is my first time using StackOverflow and I honestly couldn't be more pleased. The help I am getting is extremely profound and comprehensive; I will try your suggestions Elliot and Paul, if I encounter further struggles I will comment again. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Using your idea, Paul, I was able to get the program working to specifications. Thanks again everyone, I will definitely be a returning member.

Comment: @StarCruz I'm glad we could help.